# Ultra-metricity in sets

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

Suppose there is a set $A$ equipped with a trivial distance function. Take $D(a, a) = 0, D(a, b) = 1, a \not= b \in A$.

A set $A$ is *ultra-metric* if $D(a, c) \le \max[D(a, b), D(b, c)]$ for all $a, b, c \in A$.

Prove $A$ is ultra-metric. Is the real line ultra-metric?

I would like to know if my proof is elaborate yet concise. I shall post my answer in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your argument, though I think that you have the right idea. The worst problem is P$4$: it appears to be part of your answer to the first question, where it makes no sense, since there is no order defined on $A$. I finally realized that it actually belongs to the second question, but the union $b'\cup D(b,c)$ still makes no sense. Overall the organization is very unclear. Here’s one way that you might express the ideas more clearly:

> For the first part, it’s clear that $D$ is symmetric and that $D(a,b)=0$ if and only if $a=b$, so it suffices to show that $D(a,b)\le\max\{D(a,c),D(c,b)\}$ for all $a,b,c\in A$. Let $a,b,c\in A$. If $\max\{D(a,c),D(c,b)\}=0$, then $D(a,c)=D(c,b)=0$, and therefore $a=c=b$, in which case $$D(a,b)=0=\max\{D(a,c),D(c,b)\}\;.$$ Otherwise we have $$D(a,b)\le 1=\max\{D(a,c),D(c,b)\}\;,$$ since $0$ and $1$ are the only values assumed by $D$. Thus, $D$ satisfies the ultrametric inequality and is therefore an ultrametric on $A$.
>
> For the second part observe that $|1-2|=1=|2-3|$, but $$|1-3|=2\not\le 1=\max\{|1-2|,|2-3|\}\;,$$ so the usual metric on $\Bbb R$ is not an ultrametric.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I am new to LaTeX and I am finding it very convenient. However I will re-organize myself as I do agree this is much clearer.

Comment: @Jossie: You’re welcome. Writing mathematics clearly is sometimes harder than getting the right idea in the first place, so don’t worry if it takes some practice. As for the $\LaTeX$, you can right-click on any formula and select `Show Math As > TeX Commands` to see how it was produced.

Answer (score 1):

P1) The set A, in order for it to be ultra-metric, must satisfy $max[D(a, b), D(b, c)] = 1$; otherwise, a = b = c and A is clearly ultrametric.

P2) Thus, $a \not= b$ and so $D(a, c) <= max[D(a, b), D(b, c)]$ is logically equivalent to 1 <= 1 + 0 (or 1!) when $a \not= c$. Thus $A$ is ultra-metric.

P3) For any $a, b, c \in \Bbb R$, the ultra-metric inequality must be satisfied. Thus either $a = b = c$, in which it is trivially satisfied, $a = b \not= c : D(a, c) <= D(b, c)$ (so it is also satisfied again), or $ a \not= b \not= c$.

P4) In this case, suppose $a < b < c$. Then it suffices to prove $D(a, c) = a' <= D(a, b) = b' \cup D(b, c) = c'$. Since $b' < a'$ then $a' < c'$ must be satisfied. Clearly it isn't.

Q) The real numbers are not ultrametric for all values.